# Can placing MOVs on a 240 V input ever be a bad thing?

Tags: circuit-protection, varistor, mov

The power supply of my home lighting keeps failing. So far I have had ten identical power supplies fail. Upon inspection the thing that is always damaged is the electrolytic capacitor after the bridge rectifier (the power supply has no step-down transformer). I have always fixed the faulty capacitors by replacing them with new ones.

Aside from the power supply just being badly designed, I can only think of two reasons why they are failing: from getting too hot, or from surge voltages.

I can't really fix the temperature problem with how things are; the only thing I can do is buy electrolytic capacitors that are rated to survive in that environment; 10000 hours @ 100°C and from surge voltages that exceed the capacitor's voltage rating. I'm pretty sure they are using very cheap capacitors - that's why they are failing so fast.

To solve the surge problem I am thinking of placing a MOV on the AC input of the circuit so that the capacitor and the bridge rectifier won't be exposed to surges. The original circuit does not have any protection against surges. I was wondering if my adding MOVs to the circuit can cause problems, because I am essentially modifying the circuit. I don't think there will be, but I am just making sure.

Comment: MOVs can only withstand a limited number of cycles.

Comment: @DKNguyen that is interesting because datasheets (the brands i have looked at) does not mention life-cycles. By limited about how many are we talking here?

Comment: That's part of the problem. It's kind of unknown. Seems to depend on the energy level of the spikes. TVS diodes (whether unitidirectional or bidirectional which could be used for AC depending on where you want to place them in the circuit) do not have a wear mechanism but aren't produced as large (lower power levels).

Comment: @DKNguyen so would it be good to have them nonetheless? I do see power supplies that have them

Comment: @DKNguyen Im pretty sure these power supplies are dirt cheap, the capacitor + the MOV will cost me 1$ per powersupply. If it still fails after this fix then i will toss the power supplies for a branded one. If i can make it to last atleast a year with this fix then it will be worth it. One of my worries is that when the MOV do fail they might be a dead short which can become a fire hazard

Comment: You will need to add a fuse. With gross overload MOVs explode. Decent power supplies would already have a fuse and MOV. I would suggest you review the environmental specs of the power supply in your application. If you’re running them full load with inadequate ventilation, then even the best power supplies will fail prematurely.

Comment: @Kartman To be fair, with gross overload most things explode.

Comment: @DKNguyen - have you seen a MOV explode? It’s not pretty. You’ll find that many manufacturers will put a heat-shrink or similar shroud around them to contain it.  Nevertheless the OP is mistaken in that adding a MOV will cure his problem - it won’t. The impedance of mains surges can be very low, so the average MOV can’t soak it up and would blow the fuse, explode or both.

Comment: @Kartman Yeah mains has a lot of power behind it.

Comment: Many of the PC power supplies had a 240/110V switch. Over here, we have 240V. Sometimes the switch was in the wrong position. BAM! The internal MOVs would explode. For the most part you could replace the MOVs and the fuse to repair the PSU, so the MOVs did their job.

Comment: @DKNguyen MOVs degrade with each overvoltage event they clamp, and their withstand voltage may come down and leakage current can go up, so thermal runaway is a common problem, and both Bourns and Littelfuse MOV application notes do mention that MOVs can fail short.

Comment: What power supplies are we talking about here, exactly? It sounds like they're just really crappy. And honestly, I'd keep something that's _known to fail_ away from mains electricity. No sense risking a fire.

Comment: @Justme I stand corrected. They can fail short.

Comment: @Kartman How about i place a TVS diode across the capacitor? or its better to let the capacitor fail as it will only pop, rather than a TVS that might still become a dead short.

Comment: MOVs are generally more robust than TVS diodes. If the power is so bad it causes MOVs to fail, then a TVS is of little use. Your assumption is bad power is the cause of the psu failure. A MOV won’t fix that nor will a TVS. Suggestion - get yourself a good quality psu and see how that lasts compared with your current psus. If it doesn’t fail over time then you have your answer. Or you can try and patch up a poor psu.

Comment: @Kartman Im attempting to patch it up first as a good powersupply would cost me about 20$ a piece. The cost of repairing them is at worst 2$ a piece. Having 80 of these really adds up. Id like to try to patch it up first, if it will last a considerable amount of time then it will be worth it, if not , i will have to shell out some serious $$$.

Answer (score 4):

From [Littelfuse](https://m.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/trainings/littelfuse_varistor_mov_products_training.pdf.pdf), here is an estimate of MOV lifetime vs. energy absorbed.

[image]

In my experience they always fail shorted until they burn enough to physically come apart.

Comment: I think its also for the best it fails short, as that would indicate the circuit is exposed extreme voltages. And as mentioned by Autistic, MOVs used in input protection are usually paired with fuses .

Comment: @DrakeJest I disagree (that it's for the best), but we can't pick and choose how solid-state physics works. Semiconductors tend to fail shorted unless physically damaged. A fuse (or equivalent such as fusible resistor) would be mandatory for safety approvals, but not all stuff on the market meets even the minimum standards.

Answer (score 2):

Good to ask. MOVs may not solve your problem with power supply failure. Do be careful, because some MOVs fail into a low resistance state and can get very hot; they can even explode. A metal box is good.  MOV after fuse is good. MOV on separate fuse is good. MOV close to delicate SMD parts is bad.

Answer (score 2):

> So far I have 10 of the same power supply failed. Upon inspection the thing that is always get damaged is the Electrolytic Capacitor after the bridge rectifier (the power supply has no step down transformer). I have always fixed the faulty capacitor by replacing them with a new one.

We'll need to see a legible picture of the front and back of the PCB with the capacitor on it, as well as the ratings of the capacitor you have used as a replacement.

There are billions of devices out there that have bulk DC capacitors attached to line rectifiers. It's not very hard to get them to last long enough for the capacitor to fail from "old age".

If you buy the capacitor from reliable sources, e.g. DigiKey, Mouser, etc. but not Aliexpress or eBay, then if the capacitor is still failing then you've not used a high enough rating. Rectified 240V mains at high line is about 370VDC peak. You need 450V capacitor, and its ripple rating must not be exceeded. You will have to measure the ripple current through a replacement capacitor, and consult the datasheet to make sure you stay *well* within the specs. Typically some derating would be applied, so e.g. you'd want to stay below 1/2-1/3rd of the rated ripple current for longevity.

The hours rating on a capacitor only applies when the capacitor is used within its ratings.

You've assumed that the capacitors fail due to overvoltage, and that may well be the case, but it'd be prudent to eliminate more mundane causes of trouble:

1. Exceeding ripple current rating.
2. Exceeding DC working voltage rating in high line condition.
3. Forgetting that the full bridge rectifier output voltage is 1.4 times the RMS sine line voltage, e.g. a 350V voltage rating is insufficient, and a 400V rating would leave almost no margin.

In cases of under-rated capacitors, the replacement may be physically bigger or use a different package, so the replacement may need to be mounted outside of the PCB, connected by short lengths of hookup wire, and a bigger case would need to be used to house the PCB and the new capacitor.

Comment: Hi ! Wow its been a year already since i asked this question, Im proud to say that non of the "upgraded" power supply failed after about 1 year and 1 month. I did get high tier capacitors 450V rated rubycons. As well i placed 10nF caps on the input AC (forgot the reason). No MOVs were placed.

Comment: Pretty good then! I'm glad that quality capacitors have solved the problem. 10nF across the AC input shunts high slew rate spikes without letting them pollute the rest of the circuit, so that's a good thing. It also prevents the trace inductances from ringing due to those spikes.